# How to convert x y coordinates to hexbin center coordinates

Tags: r, hexagonal-tiles

I'm aware of the hexbin package, but I don't want to summarize the data at this point. I don't draw my plots in R, so I have no need for hexbin objects or many other things in this package.

I simply want to convert/round each point's coordinates to the xy coordinates of the center of the hexagon that contains the point. In other words, instead of the hexbin function returning a hexbin object, I want to return x and y coordinates of hexagon centers that correspond to the input coordinates.

I assumed I would find something useful in the source code of the hexbin function, but I'm kinda lost there. I don't want to write my own function if it's already been done, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your hexbin with desired bin sizes to an object and then check the structure.  The center of mass is given by `@xcm` and `@ycm`.  See `?hexbin`.

An example is shown below.

```
library(hexbin)
mtcars_hexbin <- hexbin(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp, xbins = 5, IDs= TRUE)
str(mtcars_hexbin)

# The x, y of center of mass are given by:
mtcars_hexbin@xcm
mtcars_hexbin@ycm
```

Edited to answer comment: If IDs=TRUE, then the output @cID gives the cell number to which each original non-aggregated points belong to. @cell gives you the cell number associated with @xcm, @ycm center of mass coordinates. @count tells you how many points belong to a cell.

```
mtcars_hexbin@cID
mtcars_hexbin@cell
mtcars_hexbin@count
```

Comment: I know that. But like I said, it is already summarized (i.e. one row for each hexagon).  I want to identify the correct hexbin for each individual point in my non-aggregated list of coordinates.

Comment: If you set `IDs=TRUE`, `@cID` returns "an integer vector of length n where cID[i] is the cell number of the i-th original point (x[i], y[i])." `@cell` gives you the cell number corresponding to the x,y center of mass.  That should give you the info you need to find which cell the original points belong to, and the x,y coordinates of that cell.

Comment: I knew it had to be right in front of my face. That works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, `xcm` and `ycm` are not actually the geometric centers of the hexagon, they are the weighted center of mass of the points inluded the hexagon. You need `hcell2xy()` to get the center coordinates.